# Delete only messages of a member on mention

Tags: discord.js

I want to do a command like "c!clear @User 50" who clear 50 messages of the "@User".

"c!" is the prefix.

I have a classic clear comamnd but i don't know if i can change something to make what i want :

```
    run: async (message, args) => {
        if (!message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_MESSAGES')) return message.channel.send('Vous n\'avez pas la permission d\'utiliser cette commande.')
        const count = args[0]
        if (!/\d+/.test(count)) return message.channel.send('Veuillez indiquer un nombre de messages à supprimer.')
        if (count < 1 || count > 99) return message.channel.send('Le nombre de message doit être compris entre 1 et 99.')
        const { size } = await message.channel.bulkDelete(Number(count) + 1, true)
        message.channel.send(`${size - 1} messages ont été supprimés !`).then(sent => sent.delete({timeout: 3e3}))
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TextChannel.bulkDelete() also accepts a Collection of messages as a parameter (as a number won't work, you wanna delete a specific user's messages).

Fetch a collection from MessageManager in a channel, and pass it along to bulkDelete()

```js
msg.channel.messages.fetch(messages => {
    msg.channel.bulkDelete(messages.filter(m => m.author.id === msg.mentions.members.first().id)).then(() => {
        //handle result here
    })
})
```

Of course, you should errortrap and adapt the code for your use cases.

Check out the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=bulkDelete) on this

Comment: This works for me, i forgot that i can use "message.filter" to get only one author